# where can I download qmysql driver?

Tags: qt

After two days of following many tutorials about how to create a QMYSQL driver for QT I give up. I keep getting errors and would like to know if it is possible to get the driver downloaded off somewhere or it has to be created on my PC in order to work ?

Thanks

Comment: It comes as part of Qt. Do you compile Qt yourself or do you use the provided packages?

Comment: No it doesn't. 
After executing qDebug()<<db.drivers();
I get following:
[Qt Message] ("QSQLITE") 
My second question is, would it be possible to use qsqlite to insert data into table ? QSQLITE seems to be able to connect to MYSQL db ...

Comment: I mean the source code comes as part of Qt. It won't be shipped by default on all platforms. If it's not available, one would have to compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

This is the official documentation:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows